# Unable to make Russian hyphenation work after (re-)installing TeX Live 2013

Tags: texlive, hyphenation, cyrillic

I have just upgraded TeX Live to 2013 on Mac OS, and installed all the Cyrillic packages i could think of, but the hyphenation in Russian stopped working.  Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[russian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

Польский язык (język polski, polszczyzna) — язык поляков, относящийся к лехитской подгруппе западнославянской группы славянской ветви индоевропейской языковой семьи.

\end{document}
```

The log output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./hyphenation-test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 21 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-russian/russianb.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Russian' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for english instead on input line 68.


Package babel Warning: No Cyrillic font encoding has been loaded so far.
(babel)                A font encoding should be declared before babel.
(babel)                Default `T2A' encoding will be loaded  on input line 111
.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2aenc.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t2aenc.dfu))))
(./hyphenation-test.aux
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd))
Overfull \hbox (43.51624pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--10
\T2A/cmr/m/n/10 Í ÎÂıËÚÒÍÓÈ ÔÓ‰„ÛÔÔÂ Á‡Ô‡‰ÌÓÒÎ‡‚ˇÌÒÍÓÈ „ÛÔÔ˚ ÒÎ‡‚ˇÌÒÍÓÈ ‚ÂÚ‚Ë
 ËÌ‰ÓÂ‚ÓÔÂÈÒÍÓÈ
[1{/Volumes/Data/Users/alexey/Library/texlive/2013basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdf
tex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./hyphenation-test.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information){/usr/local/texlive/2013bas
ic/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t2a.enc}</usr/local/texlive/201
3basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>
Output written on hyphenation-test.pdf (1 page, 18449 bytes).
SyncTeX written on hyphenation-test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on hyphenation-test.log.
```

Could you suggest me anything, how to fix it, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add one word to the minimal example and show the contents of the log file you get? Please, remove all lines `defining Unicode char ...` (that are irrelevant).

Comment: @egreg: I have pasted the output from the console window, is it enough, or should i paste from the log file instead?

Comment: The console window output is sufficient. You need to install `hyphen-russian` with TeX Live Utility. I suggest you to install the full MacTeX and forget about manually installing packages.

Comment: @egreg: full MacTeX is too big.  I have hyphen-russian installed, TeX Live Utility shows it as installed.

Comment: Try with `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` from a Terminal window (you'll need to supply an administrator password, your normal password should be good).

Comment: Oh! I forgot: did you install the `ruhyphen` package?

Comment: It worked, thanks! Is there no way to call `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` from the TeX Live Utility GUI? I didn't find it.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Maybe it can be a feature request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have installed the `hyphen-russian` and the `ruhyphen` TeX Live packages, then it can be a problem of non updated formats. From a Terminal window run

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --all
```

and supply your password (assuming you're an administrator of your own machine) when requested. This will recreate all format files and should fix the issue.

A note: your example code won't run correctly; if you need to print well also Polish words, it's better to load also that language. You should also specify the T2A encoding as default.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}

Польский язык (\foreignlanguage{polish}{język polski, 
polszczyzna}) — язык поляков, относящийся к лехитской подгруппе 
западнославянской группы славянской ветви индоевропейской языковой семьи.

\end{document}
```

In this way the characters with the ogonek will be proper glyphs and not constructed ones.

Comment: I've read somewhere that it is preferable to specify languages in `\documentclass` options instead of *babel* package options because this allows to omit them in *babel* options, and other packages can see which languages are used.  Is it so?

Comment: @Alexey It depends; if you declare only one language, then setting it as a global option (in `\documentclass`) may be better. If you have multiple languages, you have to be certain that the packages which benefit from these language options behave exactly like `babel` with respect to the order of the options.